# xslt following group

Tags: xslt

Old Source XML:

```
<Employees>
    <Person>
      <FirstName>Joy</FirstName>
      <IsManager>N</IsManager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <FirstName>Joyce</FirstName>
      <IsManager>N</IsManager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
      <IsManager>Y</IsManager>
    </Person>...
</Employees>
```

New Source XML:

```
<Employees>
        <Person>
        <FirstName>Joy</FirstName>
        <DetailsArray>
            <Details1>
            <IsManager>N</IsManager>
            <IsSuperviser>N</IsSuperviser>
            </Details1>
        <Details2>
                <IsManager>N</IsManager>
            <IsSuperviser>N</IsSuperviser>
            </Details2>
        </DetailsArray>
        </Person>
        <Person>
        <FirstName>Joyce</FirstName>
        <DetailsArray>
            <Details1>
            <IsManager>N</IsManager>
            <IsSuperviser>N</IsSuperviser>
            </Details1>
        <Details2>
                <IsManager>N</IsManager>
            <IsSuperviser>N</IsSuperviser>
            </Details2>
        </DetailsArray>
        </Person>
        <Person>
        <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
        <DetailsArray>
            <Details1>
            <IsManager>N</IsManager>
            <IsSuperviser>N</IsSuperviser>
            </Details1>
        <Details2>
                <IsManager>Y</IsManager>
            <IsSuperviser>N</IsSuperviser>
            </Details2>
    </DetailsArray>
        </Person>...
</Employees>
```

output should be:

```
    <Names>
    <Name num='1'>Joe</Name>
    <Name num='2'>Joy</Name>
    <Name num='3'>Joyce</Name>
    ....
    </Names>
```

This source XML has some adjustments when compared to previous XML. Here the new condition is "The person may be linked to 2projects or 2tasks", so that i need the output to start from the person with IsManager='Y' even if IsManager is 'y' in Details2 tag of DetailsArray. The output should not have duplications of Names. For suppose if we sort The names will be duplicated..

Thanks for the Previous answers..

Comment: the text of your question is somewhat unclear, can you make it bit more comprehensible ?

Comment: What do you mean "cyclic output"? The above output doesn't look "cyclic" in any sense that I know. Also, showing us your code attempt will help us understand your intent.

Comment: @LarsH - Of course my answer was a bit of a guess, but there is one obvious sense in which his output is cyclic. It starts at the first manager and then processes all elements in order, cycling back around to the beginning to get all elements before the first manager. My answer below should make it clear.

Comment: @lwburk, ok, I see that now. Maybe "get the above cyclic output when the person have IsManager='Y'" means "put them in order starting from the person who has IsManager='Y' and cycling back to the beginning." I wouldn't say the output is cyclic in any obvious sense, but the ordering is.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest and simplest solution :)

Comment: I also added an extensive explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**. As lwburk points out, the original solution of this answer just sorts the nodes by `IsManager`.

Here is a solution that finds the first manager, prints it out, then cycles through the remaining people (cycling back to the beginning, if needed).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="Employees">

    <xsl:variable name="position" select="count(Person) - count(Person/IsManager[. = 'Y'][1]/../following-sibling::*)" />

    <xsl:call-template name="person">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="Person/IsManager[. = 'Y'][1]/../FirstName" />
        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="'1'" />
    </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:for-each select="Person[position() &gt; $position]">            
            <xsl:call-template name="person" />
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="Person[position() &lt; $position]">
            <xsl:call-template name="person" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="person">
    <xsl:param name="name" select="FirstName" />
    <xsl:param name="position" select="position() + 1" />   

    <Name>
        <xsl:attribute name="num"><xsl:value-of select="$position" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name" />
    </Name>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Old answer**.

I'm not sure about your question, but I think you want to get all the names starting from the person with `IsManager = Y`. You can use `<xsl:sort>` by the `IsManager` value. Don't forget to specify "descending" in the attribute "order" (otherwise, the person with `IsManager = Y` will be the last one).

I wrote an example that works with your input data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="Employees">
    <xsl:for-each select="Person">
        <xsl:sort select="IsManager" order="descending" />

            <Name>
                <xsl:attribute name="num">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="FirstName" />

            </Name>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: No down-vote, but I don't think so. This just sorts by the `IsManager` flag. He's looking to cycle starting at the first manager.

Answer (score 1):

**This short and simple transformation** (no modes, no variables, and only three templates):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <Names>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Person[IsManager='Y'][1]"/>
  </Names>
 </xsl:template>    

 <xsl:template match="Person[IsManager='Y']">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "FirstName |../Person[not(generate-id()=generate-id(current()))]
                /FirstName
   ">
   <xsl:sort select=
    "generate-id(..) = generate-id(/*/*[IsManager = 'Y'][1])"
   order="descending"/>
   <xsl:sort select=
     "boolean(../preceding-sibling::Person[IsManager='Y'])"
     order="descending"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="FirstName">
  <Name num="{position()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></Name>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML** (the same one as provided by @lwburk):

```
<Employees>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Joy</FirstName>
        <IsManager>N</IsManager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Joyce</FirstName>
        <IsManager>N</IsManager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
        <IsManager>Y</IsManager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Professor X</FirstName>
        <IsManager>N</IsManager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Songey</FirstName>
        <IsManager>Y</IsManager>
    </Person>
</Employees>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Names>
   <Name num="1">Joe</Name>
   <Name num="2">Professor X</Name>
   <Name num="3">Songey</Name>
   <Name num="4">Joy</Name>
   <Name num="5">Joyce</Name>
</Names>
```

**Explanation**:

1. This is a typical case of sorting using multiple keys.
2. The highest priority sorting criteria is whether the Person parent is the first manager.
3. The second priority sorting criteria is whether the parent Person is following a manager.
4. We use the fact that when sorting booleans `false()` comes before `true()`, therefore we are processing the sorted nodelist in descending order.

Comment: This fails when there is no Person with IsManager = Y (my solution fails in that case, too :( ). It would be a very good solution if it just cycles the "Persons" when there is no manager.

Comment: @Alberteddu: **The problem supposes that there would be at least one manager**. It doesn't mention that there might be no manager and it doesn't postulate what output to produce for such input. I attribute this new requirement to your imagination -- but my imagination is different :)

Comment: It is just the uncontrollable urge to respond in detail considering the possible issues resulting from the solution being proposed, regardlessly on the precise and accurate list of the needs of the OP. Like some kind of personal challenge:) But yes, maybe we have different imaginations.

Comment: @Alberteddu: If the OP confirms that new requirement it is very easy to accomodate it in my solution -- no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to start at the the first manager and then processes all `Person` elements in order, cycling back around to the beginning to get all elements before the partition element.

The following stylesheet achieves the desired result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Employees/Person"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Person[IsManager='Y'][1]">
        <Name num="1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="FirstName"/>
        </Name>
        <!--  partition -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Person" mode="after"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../Person" mode="before">
            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="last() - position() + 1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Person" mode="after">
        <Name num="{position() + 1}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="FirstName"/>
        </Name>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Person[not(IsManager='Y') and 
              not(preceding-sibling::Person[IsManager='Y'])]" mode="before">
        <xsl:param name="pos" select="0"/>
        <Name num="{position() + $pos}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="FirstName"/>
        </Name>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Person"/>
    <xsl:template match="Person" mode="before"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note:** 1) This solution requires there be at least one manager present in the source; 2) This might not be a very efficient solution because it requires multiple passes and uses `preceding-sibling` to test group membership (for elements before the partition element).

Example input:

```
<Employees>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Joy</FirstName>
        <IsManager>N</IsManager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Joyce</FirstName>
        <IsManager>N</IsManager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
        <IsManager>Y</IsManager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Professor X</FirstName>
        <IsManager>N</IsManager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>Songey</FirstName>
        <IsManager>Y</IsManager>
    </Person>
</Employees>
```

Output:

```
<Name num="1">Joe</Name>
<Name num="2">Professor X</Name>
<Name num="3">Songey</Name>
<Name num="4">Joy</Name>
<Name num="5">Joyce</Name>
```